# Building JAR files in a Heroku app

Tags: heroku, jar, proguard

I have a web app running on Heroku from which I need to build and make available a JAR file when a user of the app requests it. I also need to run ProGuard on the generated JAR file. Is it possible to do this on Heroku?

Answer (score 0):

We're working on exposing Heroku build infrastructure as services and what you describe is a use case that we want to support. You might be able to get something working by using or reverse-engineering `heroku-push`: https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-push

Here's the server-side bit that actually builds code: https://github.com/ddollar/anvil

Ryan Brainard has built a Java wrapper for Anvil: https://github.com/ryanbrainard/janvil